# Design Question on mapping the data for the same Country codes in C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have country codes from Active Directory coming as below depending on the user.
"US01", "UK01", "AUS01".

I have another internal application which gives the country code as "United States of America", "United Kingdom", "Australia", "Ireland".

On the UI, I want to display the friendly country names as they are coming from internal application. Without going to database (for another table), I am trying to map these two country codes in C#.NET.

```
Ex:
```

US01 - United States of America

UK01 - United Kingdom

AUS01 - Australia

I am Wondering how to do this mapping? 
Appreciate your time.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any common ID that is shared between the two? In other words, how would a program know that US01 is equivalent to United States of America?

Comment: It seems like you may have to go to the database?  How else can you tell that "US01" is the code for "United States of America"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think , you need to Create a Static Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string,string> mapTwoValues = new Dictionary<string,string>();

mapTwoValues.Add("US01","United States of America");
```

and for using

```
mapTwoValues["US01"] which gives you the value as United States of America
```

Comment: This is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: This doesn't convey how to do the mapping, but how to store the mapping.  I *think* this user is wondering how to map these two lists together.  I would down vote this but the question is so unclear, I can't tell what this user wants.

Comment: Please downvote it but if i can create a xml file and read that file into static dictionary so how come it is maintainance nightmare?

Comment: Mine is minimum list of coutries where my corporate is: Dictionary would work. For maintenance, i could put these in Resource files.

Answer (score 0):

If you could restrict your use to only ISO country codes, you can do the following:

```
var regionInfo = new RegionInfo("GB");
Console.WriteLine(info.EnglishName);
```

Output:

```
United Kingdom
```

(Note that "UK" is not an ISO country code).

Otherwise, you *should* go to the database.

Comment: @Saurabh: Are you out of your mind? I show that you can use built-in functionality to convert the international standard for country codes to their full English name. If the user can't restrict to ISO country codes and needs to use names that are stored in a database then he should get that mapping from the database. Period.

Comment: @Jason : And i am saying that just create a XML file and store mapping there so that you can show what ever you want to show why over complicate things and you don't have an unwanted databse table to just store 3 values

Comment: @Saurabh: Your answer has nothing to do with whether or not my answer is helpful. You are indicating it is not with your question and your downvote. Mine is helpful or not helpful independent of yours. Retaliatory downvotes are uncool. Why do you assume it's three; there are over 200 countries in the world?

Comment: i don't assume , i am answering what ever be the data present in the question and question does not say about 200 or 2000 countries ? And i don't downvote you on the basis of the you downvote me or somebudy else i downvote because i don't find your answer helpful an

Comment: So in your mind, a question that was about all the country codes in the world should include all 200 in their question? Note that the OP says "Ex:".

Comment: I think the real problem with this answer, if there is one, is that the OP doesn't seem to have control over the input or output formats of the "country codes": they're getting "AUS01" from Active Directory and "Australia" from some internal system, and want to map *those* to each other. That said, I think this is the ideal solution if you *can* ensure your input is an ISO country code, and disagree with @Saurabh's objections.